# How to remove or disable "Floating Formula box" that appears after double clicking the cell containing formula?

Tags: excel

I have very large formula that is used on a **cell**.When i double click the **cell** to check which cells are being used in the formula(Visual representation), the floating formula box covers all the cells .Is there a way to disable this floating formula box ?

[image]

Comment: If you need to edit the formula what will you do then? Otherwise make cell properties `Hidden` and protect the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to select the cell, then click on the formula bar (edit box at the top) instead of double clicking on the cell.

Double clicking:

[image]

Clicking on the formula bar:

[image]